# Один fragment в двух activity

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity

Есть activity (в портретной ориентации) которая использует 2-ва fragmenta один под другим. Нужно вывести один из fragment на весь экран в альбомной ориентации. Вопрос как передать и использовать этот готовый фрагмент в другой activity. Или есть другой способ это сделать.

Answer (score 0):

Вкратце, никак. Несмотря на то, что это возможно, фрагменты не задумывались как переходящие от активити к активити элементы.

Вам необходимо создать новый экземпляр такого же фрагмента в новой активити и инициализировать его теми же данными, что фрагмент на предыдущей активити. Данные чаще всего либо [передаются между активити](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/67-urok-28-extras-peredaem-dannye-s-pomoschju-intent.html) через `Intent` с помощью [`Parcelable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) объектов или же хранятся где-то централизовано таким образом, что обе активити могу получить их относительно быстро.